# webpack split source code into smaller files

Tags: webpack, code-splitting

I know that there is code split in webpack that allow us to slit vendor codes into another chunk. However, as the project grow big, I would like to split the source code into many smaller files as well. For example, the vendor.js is now 400kb and the main.js is about 1MB (uglified). I would like to make it into :

main.js (which require)
  - model.js
  - network.js
  ...

Is there any other way to do that instead of using require.ensure?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/

Comment: I know CommonChunkPlugin and it is useful in Code Split. However, it only supports splitting vendor (node_modules, bower_components...) out of source code. What I want to do is break down the source code, too.

Comment: just use 'common' entry point for your code and it will split to chunks too

Comment: I had tried it, too. However, assume that I have a PhotoPage and NewsPage, both are using PostComponent. When I define PostComponent as separated entry, it appears that webpack must merge PhotoPage & NewsPage into one, so, the 2 other files are only 380B which has no content at all. and the merged file appears to have the same size as when it leaves default (main.js is 1.5MB). Still does not know why...

Comment: According to Webpack document: "If two chunks contain the same modules, they are merged into one. This can cause chunks to have multiple parents.  
If a module is available in all parents of a chunk, it’s removed from that chunk.  
If a chunk contains all modules of another chunk, this is stored. It fulfills multiple chunks."